# @@Identity returns 0 from Access Frontend (SQL Server Express backend)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, identity-column

I have been all over the web looking for a way to fix this, and all the answers seem to tell me that I am doing this correctly.  I have inherited this Access / SQL Server database, and I cannot seem to get this piece to work.

I am executing a fairly basic SQL `INSERT` query that works fine. I have checked it several times. Once the query executes, I am attempting to get the identity value back out of it to use for the rest of my code.

Here is my code:

```
db.Execute (SQLStr)

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")
InNo = rs(0)
Debug.Print InNo
rs.Close
db.Close
```

This always returns a value of 0 for `InNo`. I have tried several different methods but I cannot seem to get this working.

I have also used this method from the SQL Server directly, and querying the `@@Identity` works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: I believe you have to join the two SQL statements - they are executed in different contexts, so the second statement doesn't have the same scope. And yeah, use `SCOP_IDENTITY()` too.

Comment: Instead of using pass through sql (which btw is highly likely to vulnerable to sql injection) you should create an insert stored procedure and include and OUTPUT parameter for SCOPE_IDENTITY. This gives you a lot more control over what is happening AND you will have parameterized queries instead of executing a string with user inputs.

Comment: marc_s - I have read that, but have been unable to get that working as well.  Do you have any code suggestions?

Comment: Sean - This is an internal database only, so I am not worried about security much (especially since 99% of my users are computer illiterate. ), but I will take a look at stored procedures.

Comment: Luaan - I have tried that, but Access does not allow you to join the statements and run them together at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suspecting that you are running `SELECT @@IDENTITY` on your local Access database, which of course doesn't know what `@@IDENTITY` is.

I'm not 100% sure, though, because you didn't show your whole code and I don't know what `db` is.
If `db` is `CurrentDB`, then the `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset` line opens a `DAO.Recordset` which **does** execute the query on your local Access database.

If my suspicion is correct, then you need to open the recordset where you execute `SELECT @@IDENTITY` via [pass-through query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242244/6884), so it actually runs on the SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little stingy on my copy paste.  I am using currentdb, and all of my tables are linked tables from the SQL Server.

Comment: I thought so. So I was right - you need to execute `SELECT @@IDENTITY` via pass-through query, so it's actually executed by SQL Server, not by Access.

Comment: That works.  Had to go find out how to write a pass through query to do that, but it significantly cleaned up my code and it actually works now.