# Use function call in passthrough query?

Tags: ms-access, pass-through, passthru

I have a passthrough query in an Access 2010 application, which I'm using to call a stored procedure on a SQL Server backend. The stored procedure takes a parameter that I need to make dynamic. The problem is this:

`Execute spMyProc 'userName'` works as expected.

`Execute spMyProc getUserName()` generates a "syntax error at ')'" message.

**Is it possible to use a function as a parameter in a pass-through query?**

Also, I should note that I'm migrating a complex Access application to SQL server, and I'm really not well-versed in what I'm doing. Any suggestions on things I'm doing incorrectly will be gratefully received. This particular question is rising from an attempt to change the Record Source of a Form from a simple select statement in the Record Source property to something that can be run on the server.

Comment: What is getUserName() - SQL Server or Access function?  Access I'm assuming...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass")
  .SQL = "exec spMyProc '" & getUserName() & "'"
  .Execute
End With
```

Because getUserName() is a local VBA function, then you need to pre-evaluate the actual string sent to SQL server. As above shows using a saved pass-though is "handy" since you don't have to deal with connection strings etc.

Comment: That's an excellent idea, especially since I'm going to face this situation multiple times. thanks!