# Create a passthrough QueryDef with DAO and a ODBC-Connection by VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

My goal is to create a QueryDef by vba, that is the same as I can create in the GUI.

This are the Steps, that I use in the GUI:

1. Create the query
2. Set it as passthrough
3. Set the ODBC connection string
4. Enter the statement

[image]

How can I set this by VBA and use the queryDef as RecordSource in the current form?

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("test", "select * from test;")

'passthrough?
'connection string?
'set as RecordSource?
```

I found out, that there is a Properties-Collection. When I investigate a GUI-made query, I see that there the connection-String is in item 6:

```
Debug.Print qdfTmp.Properties.Item(6).Name
> Connect
```

You can find the other setting alos, but I do not know how to set them with VBA.

Comment: https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/sqlquerychat/sql-help/data-query/access-vba-how-to-create-a-query-programmatically/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Passthrough query as basis for a DAO recordset in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241898/sql-server-passthrough-query-as-basis-for-a-dao-recordset-in-access)

Comment: ^^ Setting `.Connect` turns the querydef into a Pass-Through query.

Comment: Yes, looks like a duplicate. But the given answer is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy method is to *create and check* a PT query, then *save* it, reserve it for this form, and set the form to have this query as its RecordSource.

To use it, all you need is to adjust the SQL as needed:

```vb
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ThisFormPTQuery")
qdf.SQL = "select * from test;"
```

and then open the form.

**Edit**:

To create a copy of a "master" query:

```
DoCmd.CopyObject , "NewQuery", acQuery, "MasterQuery"
```

Comment: I thought about that but the Problem is, to reserve it for the form. Is there a way to use the predefioned query as blueprint for a new one?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ThisFormPTQuery") to get the prdefined query?

Comment: @doev: Certainly. Thanks. I've corrected the code line.

Comment: Working example of create and run  Passthrough Query .[link](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=95209)

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier method. Just create the query definition and add a connection string. This will do the trick.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf as DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("test", "select * from test;")
qdf.Connect = "ODBC;Driver=...;Server=...etc."
db.QueryDefs.Refresh
```